# PublisherAdView becomes null after onAdLoaded & onAdFailed

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play-services, synthetic

The code:

```
private fun initAds() {
    val adRequest = PublisherAdRequest.Builder().build()
    pavDetail.loadAd(adRequest)
    pavDetail.adListener = object : AdListener() {
        override fun onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded()
            pavDetail.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

        override fun onAdFailedToLoad(i: Int) {
            pavDetail.visibility = View.GONE
            super.onAdFailedToLoad(i)
        }
    }
}
```

`pavDetail` is `com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView` and I get it by kotlinx synthetic from XML layout.

This code sometimes throws `IllegalStateException` because `pavDetail` mysteriously becomes null in `onAdLoaded` & `onAdFailedToLoad`.

I made it `pavDetail?.visibility` to prevent the crash but I am not sure this will work because I am suspicuous that calling `pavDetail` itself may throw that exception. Remember this is not `NullPointerException` this is a `IllegalStateException` giving message `pavDetail must not be null`.

Hence, I ask why `pavDetail` becomes null and how to prevent the crash.

Comment: do you use it in a `ViewHolder`?

Comment: `initAds` method called by `onChanged` method of `ViewHolder` if there is no data. If there is data, it is called by `onActivityCreated` in a `Fragment`

Comment: Do your `ViewHolder` implements `LayoutContainer`?

Comment: Sorry I mixed your question by seeing `ViewHolder` as `ViewModel`. This code is in a `Fragment` which is a `ViewPager` item, so it does't use `ViewHolder`. Hence, `initAds` method called by `onChanged` method of `ViewModel` if there is no data in `LiveData`. If there is data, it is directly called by `onActivityCreated`.